# tcp data modified after socket transmission

Tags: c++, tcp

I am writing a program to transmit data between two machines with tcp/ip socket in C/C++.  The programs checks the size of each read and write to make sure the correct size of data being transferred. I also implement a checksum verification to make sure the correct data are transferred.  Most of time there is no problem.  Once a while, like, once in 50,000 times, I notice the data received is the same length as the sending side but some of its content were altered. The altered portion is always 64 bytes long.  Below is my code of send and read. Please help me figure out how this can happen and how to prevent it. Thanks!

```
bool WriteSocket(int pSocket, unsigned char* pData, uint32_t pNumBytes, uint32_t &pNumBytesWritten, uint32_t &pNumWrites)
{
    int rc;
    unsigned char* currPos = pData;
    uint32_t numFailures = 0;

    pNumBytesWritten = 0;
    pNumWrites = 0;
    while ( true )
    {
        rc = write(pSocket, currPos, pNumBytes);
        pNumWrites++;
        if ( rc < 0 )
        {
            if ( errno == EINTR )
                continue;
            numFailures++;
            if ( numFailures >= 5 )
                break;
            else
                continue;
        }
        pNumBytesWritten += rc;
        if ( rc == pNumBytes )
            return true;
        pNumBytes -= rc;
        currPos += rc;
        numFailures = 0;
    };
    return false;
};

bool ReadSocket(int pSocket, unsigned char* pData, uint32_t pNumBytes)
{
    int rc;
    unsigned char* currPos = pData;
    uint32_t numFailures = 0;

    while ( true )
    {
        rc = read(pSocket, currPos, pNumBytes);
        if ( rc < 0 )
        {
            if ( errno == EINTR )
                continue;
            numFailures++;
            if ( numFailures >= 5 )
                break;
            else
                continue;
        }
        if ( rc == pNumBytes )
            return true;
        pNumBytes -= rc;
        currPos += rc;
        numFailures = 0;
    }; 
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Use bracket for `if/else` statement to make your code more readable

Comment: Aside: no such language as C/C++.

Comment: You haven't tested for a zero return in your read method.

Answer (score 0):

If a socket read/write fails for any reason other than EINTR or EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK, you should consider that as a fatal error. Do not retry the operation, just stop and close the socket. But your code doesn't do that, it keeps trying to repeat the failed operation.

Also, when reading, you are not handling the case where the read returns 0 when the peer disconnects *gracefully*. A socket error is not reported in that case.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
bool WriteSocket(int pSocket, unsigned char* pData, uint32_t pNumBytes, uint32_t &pNumBytesWritten, uint32_t &pNumWrites)
{
    int rc;
    uint32_t numRetries = 0;

    pNumBytesWritten = 0;
    pNumWrites = 0;

    while ( pNumBytes > 0 )
    {
        rc = write(pSocket, pData, pNumBytes);
        if ( rc < 0 )
        {
            if ( errno == EINTR )
                continue;

            if ( (errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK) )
            {
                ++numRetries;
                if ( numRetries < 5 )
                {
                    // TODO: use select() or epoll() w/ timeout to
                    // detect when then socket is writable again...
                    continue;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        ++pNumWrites;
        pNumBytesWritten += rc;
        pNumBytes -= rc;
        pData += rc;

        numRetries = 0;
    }

    return true;
}

bool ReadSocket(int pSocket, unsigned char* pData, uint32_t pNumBytes)
{
    int rc;
    uint32_t numRetries = 0;

    while ( pNumBytes > 0 )
    {
        rc = read(pSocket, pData, pNumBytes);
        if ( rc < 0 )
        {
            if ( errno == EINTR )
                continue;

            if ( (errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK) )
            {
                ++numRetries;
                if ( numRetries < 5 )
                {
                    // TODO: use select() or epoll() w/ timeout to
                    // detect when then socket is readable again...
                    continue;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        else if ( rc == 0 )
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            pNumBytes -= rc;
            pData += rc;

            numRetries = 0;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `++pNumBytes;` is not correct, and neither is your handling of `rc == 0`.

Comment: @user207421 there is no `++pNumBytes;` statement in the code I provided. And if the peer disconnects *gracefully* (sends a `FIN` packet), a subsequent read will report 0 bytes received, not a read error.

Comment: Why `if (numRetries < 5)` ?  5 seems like kind of an arbitrary number.  I'd think that if you want to implement a blocking read/write, the socket should be in blocking mode (or if it must be in non-blocking mode, you could implement a block via select()/epoll() *without* a timeout, such that execution blocks there until it is ready for read/write)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yes, 5 is arbitrary. I was merely preserving the OP's original logic of retrying non-fatal operations, just adding more logic to catch fatal errors. I agree that `select()`/`epoll()` is better, but I don't agree that a timeout should be omitted. After a point, too much latency may not always be acceptable to business-critical processes. It depends on the OP's particular needs. I've used logic like I've shown in my own apps for years and they have had fairly stable connections, only failing with actual network failures, not by coding errors.